# How to virtualize a physically installed Ubuntu 10.04 into Windows 7 using Virtualbox?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-10.04, virtualbox

I currently have both Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and Windows 7 installed on my Machine in dual boot. Prior to 10.04, I was able to fully virtualize my physically installed Ubuntu setup on Windows 7 using virtualbox and grub1. I had followed this [tutorial](http://www.ltyer.com/wordpress/tutorial-boot-existing-ubuntu-partition-using-virtualbox-inside-windows). Now, I have upgraded my distribution to 10.04 LTS, removed grub1 and installed grub2 to it (since the upgrade wouldn't remove grub legacy) and tried to follow this [tutorial](http://www.ltyer.com/wordpress/tutorial-boot-ubuntu-9-10-partition-using-virtualbox-inside-windows) even though it was listed working only on 9.10. As expected, I cannot seem to boot into my OS from Win 7 with grub 2 with Virtualbox. Dual booting into any OS though works perfectly.

I get the following grub2 error when launching the virtual vdi: Unknown file system.

Does anyone know a related issue or tutorial (or better, someone that knows the answer!) that could help me virtualize my physical installation of Ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 0):

Physical disks inside of Vbox is almost always painful.  You can use raw disk access(not recommended) or reinstall grub from a virtual livecd once a vdi is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can allow raw disk access, check http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk

Comment: Well that is exactly what I am doing just like the tutorials impose when using VBoxManage

Comment: Are you 100% sure nothing else is accessing the disk? check lsof. I had that error once because I left cfdisk running while I was trying to access the disk through VB.